# Claim change in Identity Server's ProfileService is not reflected in Authentication Cookie

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Identity Server 4 I am starting the login process from a SPA.

After I login I have the following claims on IS4 app authentication cookie:

```
sub                              1
AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp    RRHNY65RQMUHTXXSIZKT2YORA3QQ2WAC
role                             Admin
preferred_username               info@example.com
name                             info@example.com
email                            info@example.com
email_verified                   true
amr                              pwd
idp                              local
auth_time                        1598736198
```

Why does the `name` claim gets the email as its value?

I then implemented the ProfileService to replace the `name` claim by the actual user name.

When I check the claims on the spa the replacement was done ...

But on IS4 application the Authentication Cookie still gets the email as `name` claim.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was how ASP.NET Core 3.1 defines the Claims.

I then implemented `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` to update the `name` claim:

```
public class UserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> {

  public UserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<User> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor) { } 

  public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user) {

    ClaimsPrincipal principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;

    Claim claim = identity.FindFirst("name");
  
    if (claim != null)
      identity.RemoveClaim(claim);

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("name", user.Name));

    return principal;

  }

}
```

And now the Authentication Cookie and the Token have the same claims.

Using IdentityServer4's `ProfileService` only changes the claims on the token:

```
  public class ProfileService : IProfileService {
    
    private readonly IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> _claimsFactory;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User> claimsFactory) {
      _userManager = userManager;
      _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context) {
      // Not doing any change here
      User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
      ClaimsPrincipal principal = await _claimsFactory.CreateAsync(user); 
      context.IssuedClaims = principal.Claims.ToList();
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context) {
      User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
      context.IsActive = (user != null) && user.Enabled;
    }
    
  }
```

I suppose ProfileService is more useful when not using Asp.Net Core Identity?

Answer (score 0):

Ar the claims correct in the Identity Token?

If it is correct in the ID-token, then you probably have some claims transformation implemented in your ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: I just added an answer to my own question with the solution. I suppose what I posted is the right way to do this. What do you think?